# how to convert it in array while returnung in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

while creating an API I am having some issues while returning the data at response please help to resolve it

```
$user_role = [
            'user_id' => $data,
            'role_id' => 1,
        ];
```

my result

```
"user_role": {
        "user_id": 191,
        "role_id": 1
      }
```

I want it in an array-like below

```
"user_role": [{
        "user_id": 191,
        "role_id": 1
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user_role = [[
            'user_id' => $data,
            'role_id' => 1,
        ]];

return response()->json(["user_role" => $user_role], 200);
```